# Google spreadsheet If statement

Tags: if-statement, spreadsheet, google-sheets

I am having trouble understanding the `IF` statement.
What I am trying to do is (in php):

```
    if(isEmpty($cellA) && isNotEmpty($cellB){
        $cellA = CurrentDate;
    }
```

My attempt at doing this in the spreadsheet is:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK($A3), IF(ISBLANK($B3),"",$A3 = NOW()) ,"")
```

I get an error `error: Circular dependency detected`

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circular dependency will occur if you put that formula in either `A3` or `B3` because the formula will be referencing the cell that contains the formula, which would recursively go on forever.  Think of a very simple example - the formula `=A1` in cell `A1`. When the formula is evaluated, it sees that its value should be the value of `A1` (which is the current cell). It then finds `A1` on the sheet and tries to get its value, but as we just saw, the formula is `=A1`, so it would then go to cell `A1` (where we already are) again and try to calculate the value. This process would put you into an infinite loop, and Spreadsheets prevents this from happening by not calculating anything when it notices a cell is referencing itself, and instead warning you of a circular reference.

Also, since you can't assign values to arbitrary cells from within a formula, that `$A3 = NOW()` part is just a boolean evaluation that will return `True` or `False`. The general syntax (which it looks like you have) is `IF(<condition>, <value_if_true>, <value_if_false)`. What you are doing in PHP is actually more suited to AppScript, which is a JavaScript-esque programming language built into Google Docs. Using this you would be able to do what you look for - otherwise, you would have to create a separate column and do the calculations there. Hope that helps :)